# Conditions for $f_*(O_S)=O_B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface, $B$ a smooth curve. 
Suppose $f\colon S\to B$ is a surjective morphism.
Is there a condition for $f_*(O_S)=O_B$? (I read about a sufficient condition: the function field $K(B)$ is algebraically closed in $K(S)$, why does it hold?)

Comment: EGA III, §4, Corollaire 4.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is essentially saying that the fibers of $f$ are connected. (Why? Look at what it says on stalks, or use the theorem on formal functions). It is a necessary condition that the generic fiber is connected for this to hold. For the last statement, use the Stein factorization of the morphism: This says that $f$ can be factored as $S\to B'\to B$ where $h:S\to B'$ has $h_*O_S=O_{B'}$ and $g:B'\to B$ is finite. In particular, $K(B)\subseteq K(B')$ is a *finite* field extension. If the function field of $K(B)$ is algebraically closed in $K(S)$, then I guess it is not too hard to see that in fact $K(B)=K(B')$.

EDIT: Actually, you might want to see the answers of roy smith and J.C.Ottem at this Mathoverflow thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf